# Amazon SQS keeps returning a 403 error

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I am doing project in Laravel. For storing images I am using aws-s3. My project working very well on godaddy server but not on digital ocean server. I am getting error as,

```
Aws\Sqs\Exception\SqsException: Error executing "ReceiveMessage" on "https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/your-account-id/your-queue-name"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/your-account-id/your-queue-name` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
<?xml version="1.0"?><ErrorResponse xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/"><Error><Type>Sender</Type><Code>I (truncated...)
 InvalidClientTokenId (client): The security token included in the request is invalid. - <?xml version="1.0"?><Err......
```

Here Is a code that I used for s3 setup in my project,

*filesystem.php*

```
        's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key'    => '************',
        'secret' => '***********',
        'region' => 'ap-south-1',
        'bucket' => 'xyz',
        'options' => [
            'ServerSideEncryption' => 'AES256',
        ]
    ]
```

*.env*

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=redis
```

I am getting this error irrespective of hitting any api. I don't know where I am going wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message you've shown is for Amazon SQS (queue), not S3 (filesystem).

Answer (score 2):

Issue is documented under aws blog,

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/security-token-expired/

Please check your credentials and appropriate roles / Policies attaches to roles to access S3.

Comment: Two things... `expired` != `invalid`, so the post isn't about the same error message... and the error message isn't about S3, it's SQS.

Comment: Expired Token also gives you the same message, since it is no longer valid.

Comment: I have uploaded same project on godaddy as well as digital ocean. Project working well on godaddy server but not on digital ocean.